# Best practice for mean value of function: bar or overline or something else?

Tags: math-mode

If you have a function f, it is common to denote its mean value by a line over it, like `\bar u`. Suppose I have a function like `$f_T$`, then how should I write the mean value?

Like `$\bar f_T$`, `$\overline{f}_T$` or `$\overline{f_T}$`? Or something else? Please advise me!!!

Answer (score 4):

This seems a matter of preference to me. I personally always prefer to use `\overline`, as I find the `\bar` line to be very short (particularly if you have something wider than a single letter, like `f_T`). Apart from that preference, I'd point out two small differences between including the `_T` under the line, or not.

- If by the mean of `f_T`, you mean: the mean of `f`, and afterwards specifying some `T`, I would suggest `\overline{f}_T`
- If `f_T` is the actual function you are taking a mean of, I would suggest `\overline{f_T}`

By your description, I would suggest the second.

In general, if you are unsure, you can always make a command

```
\newcommand*\mean[1]{\overline{#1}}
```

and use `\mean{f_T}`, so you can change to `\bar` if you'd prefer that at a later point.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know a code, like your new command, where it would treat \mean{f} and \mean{f_T} differently? So for functions with a parameter like T I can choose to display it differently, with the same command?

Comment: Do you mean (haha!) `\mean{f_T}` should not be stretch over `_{T}`?